# Regression on periodic target variable

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, dataset, regression

I am trying to perform a regression on this [data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Behavior+of+the+urban+traffic+of+the+city+of+Sao+Paulo+in+Brazil) to predict the last column of the data using the first predictors in the database .

```
data=read.csv(file="~data.csv",sep=";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# separate X and Y 
# the target is Slowness in traffic (%)
names(data)[length(data)]="y"
plot(data$y,type="l")
```

[the plot i get of the last column y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWpvh.png)
Is there any kind of specific regression for these types of target variables when they are periodic .

Comment: You didn't specify what tools you're going to be using for the regression task. If you were using ```LinearRegression``` from scikit-learn, you could pre-process your data using ```PolynomialFeatures``` and play around with different orders of polynomials to see which one gives you a better fit.

Comment: Take a look at `arima` modeling.

Comment: Asking for recommendation for statistical models isn't really a specific programming question that's a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you need modeling advice, you should instead ask at [stats.se] or [datascience.se].